# How do I sort an ArrayBuffer in place?

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting

All the sort methods (`sortBy`, `sorted`, `sortWith`) seem to return a new `ArrayBuffer` and leave the original `ArrayBuffer` untouched. I want to sort an `ArrayBuffer` in place. How do I do that?

Comment: The question I marked as a duplicate is 3 years old, but as far as I can tell it's still accurate. If such a method existed, I'd expect to find it in [`scala.util.Sorting`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Sorting$), but it seems it's only available for `Array`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin maybe worth noting that protected ArrayBuffer.array is the underlying array to sort.

Comment: @som-snytt How would you pass a protected array to Java's sort method?